# Matlab Simulink showing following errror: kinematic constraints cannot be maintained

Tags: robotic-arm, matlab, simulation

I'm using simulink to get joints torque by giving motion input. I create very simple CAD model in solidworks to learn simulink. Simulink model is showing in below figure.

[image]

During update it shows no error but when I Run it shows error as

[image]

3D-CAD model is shown below figure.

[image]

Can anybody help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: The error suggests a solution. Did you follow it?

Comment: Thanks for reply @CroCo. Yes I tried after changing solver type in simscope solver configuration block and model configuration parameters but it shows same error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with simulink, but it looks like your joints are of equal length.  With the right position, it's possible to have them seize up.  Or in terms of simulations, you may be getting a matrix that is singular.